# Ada95 Traceback function produces no output

Tags: ada, gnat, ada95

Using `GNATMAKE 3.13a1 (20000509)`, the following function seems to produce no result.  That is the log messages are never written to the log, nor is the stack-trace logged.

The surrounding logs, perform normally.

```
procedure log_Stack_Trace( label : in  String;
                           memo  : in  String := "" )
is
    length : Natural := 16;
    trace  : GNAT.Traceback.Tracebacks_Array( 1..length );
begin
    trace_Debug( "--- Stacktrace [" & label & "] ---" );
    if ( "" /= memo )
    then
        trace_Debug( "---" & memo );
    end if;

    GNAT.Traceback.Call_Chain( trace, length );
    trace_Debug( GNAT.Traceback.Symbolic.Symbolic_Traceback( trace( 1..length ) ) );

end log_Stack_Trace;
```

Calling this procedure like ~

```
    trace_Debug( "Before stack-trace" );
    log_Stack_Trace( "HELLOOOO?" );
    trace_Debug( "After stack-trace" );
```

Only gives me the log-output:

> Before stack-trace
>   After stack-trace

The `--- Stacktrace [ ... ] ---` heading message (etc.) is never logged.

Is there something peculiar to GNat / Ada95 causing this?  Do I have to actually have an exception to get a stack-trace (or suchlike?).

Comment: That's a 20 year old compiler... if you're in the US, it'll be old enough to drink next year. Time for an upgrade?

Comment: You are using a version of GNAT that is almost 20 years old. Is there a reason for that?

Comment: I agree it's an old compiler, but that's the environment I inherited.  It's for an audited safety-system, so it's not so easy to just dump the compiler for a newer one.